# How to recompile Ruby and OpenSSL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, production

I'm currently setting up a server with no provisioning tool for production. The server is RHEL 6.5 and we're using Ruby `2.1.4`. The server doesn't manage Rubies via `rbenv` or `rvm`.

The problem is that when I try to do a `bundle install`, I'm getting this OpenSSL issue.

> ```
> Could not load OpenSSL.
> You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your
> Gemfile from 'https' to 'http'. Instructions for compiling with OpenSSL
> using RVM are available at http://rvm.io/packages/openssl.
> ```

In the `Gemfile`, we're using our own source for gems: `source 'http://gems.ourhost.org/'`.

I was wondering if someone already had the same problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `yum remove ruby && yum install openssl openssl-devel ruby` should do the trick

Comment: The question is kind of broad. It seems like you have not tried anything. Perhaps you should perform the compile and install, and ask a specific question when you have one.

Answer (score 3):

SSLv3 has been disabled in upstream OpenSSL, so I had to reinstall my ruby versions that don't have a patch for this with the patch that enables functioning with SSLv3 disabled. The patch is [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/801e1fe46d83c856844ba18ae4751478c59af0d1.diff). Here's what I did, using RVM (I know you said you don't use it, so you could just install ruby from source but patch this first):

```
wget https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/801e1fe46d83c856844ba18ae4751478c59af0d1.diff -O openssl.patch
rvm reinstall --patch openssl.patch 2.2.3
```

There's some more info on [this github issue](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3548), as well as people reporting success with different versions.